# Who else besides Vishnu achieves the "paramam padam" in Rig Veda?

Tags: vishnu, rig-veda

For one, Apam Napat is also said to achieve it in 2 35 14

From [Sanskrit documents.org](https://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/rigveda/roman03/RV0302.htm)

> a̱sminpa̱de pa̍ra̱me ta̍sthi̱vāṁsa̍madhva̱smabhi̍rvi̱śvahā̍ dīdi̱vāṁsa̍m |
>
> āpo̱ naptre̍ ghṛ̱tamanna̱ṁ vaha̍ntīḥ sva̱yamatkai̱ḥ pari̍ dīyanti ya̱hvīḥ || 2.035.14

[English translation](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv02035.htm) of the above mantra

> 14 While here he dwelleth in sublimest station, resplendent with the rays that never perish,
> The Waters, bearing oil to feed their offspring, flow, Youthful Ones, in wanderings about him.

Any others?

Comment: Looks like you are answering your question again saying "Apam Napat is also said to achieve it in 2 35 14". in the body itself. I see no question in the body.

Answer (score 3):

Narayana achieves the Param padam in yajurveda-

> ōm sahasraśīrṣaṁ devaṁ viśvākśaṁ viśvaśambhuvaṁ, viśvaṁ nārāyaṇaṁ
>   devamakśaraṁ **paramaṁ padam.**
>
> This universe is the Eternal Being (Narayana), the imperishable, the
>   supreme, the goal, multi-headed and multi-eyed (i.e., omnipresent and
>   omniscient), the resplendent, the source of delight for the whole
>   universe.

Param padam, the highest abode of supreme being is used in every hymn related to Lord Vishnu or his avatars.

Sometimes different names are used in Vedas for same supreme being- Apam Napat maybe another way to glorify Lord Vishnu.

Similar to how brahmanaspati of Vedas is similar to ganesha in characteristics, and has differing name than brihaspati.

Some info from wiki-

> example in Rigveda book 2 hymn 35 verse 2, described as the supreme
>   *creator deity* who *originates in the cosmic waters*. Apam
>   Napat has a *golden splendour* and is said to be kindled by the cosmic
>   waters.

Cosmic water, golden hue over dark body, paramam padam. The hymn is most likely referring to Lord Vishnu, the same characteristics are mentioned in narayana suktam.

Apam also means water, Apam the cosmic ocean or water.